# How can I concatenate a vector?

Tags: r, vector, concatenation

I'm trying to produce a single variable which is a concatenation of two chars  e.g to go from "p30s4" "p28s4" to "p30s4 p28s4".   I've tried cat and paste as shown below.  Both return empty variables.  What am I doing wrong?

```
> blah = c("p30s4","p28s4")
> blah
[1] "p30s4" "p28s4"

> foo = cat(blah)
p30s4 p28s4
> foo
NULL

> foo = paste(cat(blah))
p30s4 p28s4
> foo
character(0)
```

Comment: you're concatenating a vector, might want to change the question, but the answer is right nonetheless

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Try using:

```
> paste(blah, collapse = "")
[1] "p30s4p28s4"
```

or if you want the space in between:

```
> paste(blah, collapse = " ")
[1] "p30s4 p28s4"
```

Answer (score 13):

A alternative to the 'collapse' argument of paste(), is to use do.call() to pass each value in the vector as argument.

```
do.call(paste,as.list(blah))
```

The advantage is that this approach is generalizable to functions other than 'paste'.

Comment: `as.list(blah)` did the trick for me

Answer (score 2):

The answers to this question are great, and much simpler than mine - so I have since adopted the use of 'collapse'.

However, to promote the idea that when in doubt, you can write your own function, I present my previous, less elegant solution:

```
  vecpaste <- function (x) {
     y <- x[1]
     if (length(x) > 1) {
         for (i in 2:length(x)) {
             history
             y <- paste(y, x[i], sep = "")
         }
     }
     #y <- paste(y, "'", sep = "")
     y
 }

vecpaste(blah)
```

you can also add quotes and commas, or just about anything - this is the original version that I wrote:

```
vecpaste <- function (x) {
y <- paste("'", x[1], sep = "")
if (length(x) > 1) {
    for (i in 2:length(x)) {
        history
        y <- paste(y, x[i], sep = "")
    }
}
y <- paste(y, "'", sep = "")
y
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your use of `cat` above is that `cat(x)` writes `x` to output, not to a variable.  If you wanted to write to a string, you could do:

```
capture.output(cat(blah))
```

which as the name implies, captures the output in a string to return the desired result.  However, this is *not* the preferred method, just an explanation by way of an alternate solution.