# use dplyr to concatenate a column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `data_frame` where I would like `vector` to be the concatenation of elements in `A`. So

```
df <- data_frame(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2), A = c("a", "b", "b", "c"))
df
Source: local data frame [4 x 2]

  id A
1  1 a
2  1 b
3  2 b
4  2 c
```

Should become

```
newdf
Source: local data frame [4 x 2]

  id vector
1  1 "a b"
2  2 "b c"
```

My first inclination is to use `paste()` inside `summarise` but this doesn't work.

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(paste(A))
Error: expecting a single value
```

Hadley and Romain talk about a similar issue in the [GitHub](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/154) issues, but I can't quite see how that applies directly. It seems like there should be a very simple solution, especially because `paste()` usually *does* return a single value.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752323/r-how-can-i-concatenate-a-vector)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to collapse the values in paste

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(vector=paste(A, collapse=" "))
```

Comment: Wow, okay. Have never used `collapse` because it seems awfully similar to `sep`. This is the kind of thing I love about R!

Comment: @MrFlick, could you please advise how I can use your solution for only pasting unique values of `A` while there are duplicates values of `A` corresponding to an `ID`? Thanks!

Comment: @Alex You can use `vector=paste(unique(A), collapse=" ")`

Comment: @MrFlick, Thank you! I will try on the data and will keep you posted!

Answer (score 2):

My data frame was as:
  col1          col2

```
1           one 
1           one more
2           two
2           two
3           three
```

I needed to summarise it as follows:

col1          col3

```
1           one, one more
2           two
3           three
```

This following code did the trick:

```
    df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1,1,2,2,3), col2 = c("one", "one more", "two", "two", "five"))

    df %>%
            group_by(col1) %>%
            summarise( col3 = toString(unique(col2)))
```

Comment: But this will essentially make it a string. A comma separated string. How to get data something like  1. Design_ID 2. Vector of designs not comma separate values.