# First result repeating in array_agg and string_agg functions in postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I apologize if some of the code below is superfluous, but I am wanting to paint a picture of everything I am trying to do.

My intention is to

1. Select an element from a json array called `pickupLocations`. There are many `pickupLocations` for every `id_referral`. *See the CTE named `raw_addresses` below.*, and
2. Use a string aggregation function (e.g. `string_agg`) to create a delimited field of addresses for each `id_referral`.

In other words, I want to be able to go from

```
#id_referral    pickup_addresses
#1  4265 Hillsdale Ave. NE, Grand Rapids, MI 49525
#1  3060 Cheney Ave. NE, Grand Rapids, MI 49525
#2  805 Kendalwood St. NE, Grand Rapids, MI 49505
#2  711 Edgewood St. NE, Grand Rapids, MI 49505
```

in my `raw_addresses` CTE

to

```
#id_referral    pickup_addresses
#1  4265 Hillsdale Ave. NE, Grand Rapids, MI 49525 | 3060 Cheney Ave. NE, Grand Rapids, MI 49525
#2  805 Kendalwood St. NE, Grand Rapids, MI 49505 | 711 Edgewood St. NE, Grand Rapids, MI 49505
```

in my final select.

However, I am now getting the following results

```
#id_referral    pickup_addresses
#1  4265 Hillsdale Ave. NE, Grand Rapids, MI 49525 | 4265 Hillsdale Ave. NE, Grand Rapids, MI 49525
#2  805 Kendalwood St. NE, Grand Rapids, MI 49505 | 805 Kendalwood St. NE, Grand Rapids, MI 49505
```

When using the code below.

```
 WITH raw_addresses AS (
         SELECT sr.id AS id_referral,
        --parsing a json array which has many pickupLocations for a single id_referral
            json_array_elements(sr."pickupLocations") -> 'pickupLocationAddress' AS pickup_address
           FROM "ServiceReferrals" sr
        )
--want to roll the pickup addresses into a single pipe-delimited field (willing work through an array too as shown with array_agg, but same problem there)
 SELECT raw_addresses.id_referral,
    string_agg(cast(pickup_address as varchar(100)), '|') AS pickup_addresses
   FROM raw_addresses
  GROUP BY raw_addresses.id_referral
```

For some reason, the `string_agg` function is repeating the first value for each `id_referral`. I have also tried `agg_array` and get the same behavior.

Any thoughts as to why would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just to double-check, your CTE for `raw_addresses` actually produces the output you've described (eg. you did a `select * from raw_addresses` to get that output)?

Comment: @gerrat, no - the CTE behaves as expected. I am getting a, `pickupLocationAddress` as an element from `pickupLocations` (many for each `id_referral`). The final result only comes from the final select. `string_agg` is behaving somewhat as expected - it's just repeating the "first"  `pickupLocationAddress` (delimited by pipes) instead of delimiting each unique `pickupLocationAddress`

Comment: If anyone is trying to implement this for analysis in R (which I am), I came across this answer which gets the job done with dplyr http://stackoverflow.com/a/28752857/2364325

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using an intermediate CTE:

```
WITH raw_addresses AS (
     SELECT sr.id AS id_referral,
    --parsing a json array which has many pickupLocations for a single id_referral
        json_array_elements(sr."pickupLocations") -> 'pickupLocationAddress' AS pickup_address
       FROM "ServiceReferrals" sr
), transformed_addresses AS (
    SELECT id_referral, 
    cast(pickup_address as varchar(100)) AS pickup_address
    FROM raw_addresses
)
SELECT id_referral,
string_agg(pickup_address, '|') AS pickup_addresses
FROM transformed_addresses
GROUP BY id_referral
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't have remote access to this DB, but I'll check this out tmr.

Comment: I am still getting the same problem when I run this code on my DB. That said, as shown here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e9839/3, your code does work as expected so I am accepting the answer. My specific problems must be a non-obvious problem with my specific DB setup or table that I am unable to reproduce at this time. As stated above, I have solved this problem with a non-SQL solution for now.