# Concatenating strings using group_by and summarise in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to concatenate a column of strings together based on a grouping. I'm using code that seems identical to me to what others have used (e.g. [use dplyr to concatenate a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28752805/use-dplyr-to-concatenate-a-column)) but it isn't working, and I can't figure out why.

```
a = tibble(
       x = c(1,2,1,2),
       z = c('1','2','3','4')
   )

a %>% group_by(x) %>% summarise(val=paste(z, collapse=" "))
```

Gives:

```
   val
1 1 2 3 4
```

It acts as if there was only one group. Yet when I do a different function, the grouping works properly:

```
a %>% group_by(x) %>% tally()
# A tibble: 2 × 2
      x     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     1     2
2     2     2
```

Any idea what the issue might be?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It could be that `plyr` package was also loaded and masked the `summarise` function from `dplyr` as both of them have the same function name.  One option is to use `::` to specify the function from the `dplyr` package

```
a %>%
   group_by(x) %>%
   dplyr::summarise(val=paste(z, collapse=" "))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#      x   val
#  <dbl> <chr>
#1     1   1 3
#2     2   2 4
```